# Yii Tbgridview Not Working In Ie8 - Bootstrap TbGridView disappears in sorting, paging and filtering -IE8

Tags: gridview, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, yii

I have integrated yii bootstrap extension in to my site. I have a page where I am displaying a Grid view. Though its bootstrap, I have used TbGridView. The basic GridView functionality like, sort, paging, filtering, everything works fine in all browsers except IE8. Whenever I tried to perform sort, paging, filtering in Grid, the Grid disappears. It happens only in IE8. I have checked the jquery-yiigridview.js by debugging. especially ,

[code]

update: function (options) {

[/code]

But found nothing special. Only thing I came to understand that, In IE8, the response is not appended to the Grid (#id). Something is missing related to the ajax rendering in IE8.

Strange thing is that, I have another page where I am using a pop up using the renderPartial method. There is also a TbGridView. But that works fine in IE8.

More info:

Controller:
[code]

```
        public function actionRate()
        {
        $requestModel = new Rate('search');             
        $requestModel->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Rate']))
        $requestModel->attributes=$_GET['Rate'];                              
       $this->render('requestList', array('model'=>$requestModel)); 
        }
```

[/code]

View:

[code]

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
'id'=>'request-grid-list',
'filter'=>$model,
'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),   
'columns'=>array(               
        array(
                'name' => 'ratename',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value' => '$data->ratename',
        )
        ),));
```

[/code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After so much debugging, I found out the reason for the issue in IE8.

My first thought was the jquery-yiigridview.js. I found that, the update method in jquery-yiigridview.js for yii grid is working fine.

```
$.each(settings.ajaxUpdate, function (i, el) {
    var updateId = '#' + el;
    $(updateId).replaceWith($(updateId, $data));
});
```

Then suddenly the Grid disappeared. Yes the problem was with the "response data". Firefox and Chrome render it perfectly. But in IE8 it results in error. So I checked the response data. There was "bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar" inside my main.php layout file. When I removed that, it worked. But that's not the fix. I checked why it is breaking in IE8.

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar', array(
    'type'=>'inverse', // null or 'inverse'
    'brand'=>$brandName,
    'brandUrl'=>'#',
    'collapse'=>true, // requires bootstrap-responsive.css
    'items'=>array(
        array(
```

`'collapse'=>true` was the problem. So I removed that line. Now its working perfectly in IE8.

But that's not the end.. Next thing is.. learn,, :) :)

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

NOTE: It's a quick fix. Please share yout thoughts.